# Count the occurrences of a letter in a string with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to implement a piece of code that will return the count of the specified letter in a string.
I can do it with a for loop but I find it more elegant of a solution to use LINQ expressions.
Here is my code:

```
public static int CountAs(string countA)
{

    var test = count.Select(x => x == 'a').Count();
        
    return test;

}
```

Im trying to count how many lower case letter a's exist in the countA parameter. What is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

The method I should be using is the **Where** method instead of the **Select** method. Using this fixed my issue!! the function can be rewritten as:

```
public static int CountAs(string input)
{
   return input.Where(x => x == 'a').Count();
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use the Count method to directly filter out the desired letter:

```
public static int CountAs(string input)
{
   return input.Where(x => x == 'a').Count();
}
```

Thank you everyone that came to the rescue!!

Comment: The two methods in your update are exactly the same are they not? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.Count()` with a predicate. The `.Count()` method is used to do data calculation and based on condition (predicate).

[`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.count?view=net-5.0)

> Returns the number of elements in a sequence.

Meanwhile `.Select()` is used for data projection / display.

[`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

Thus, your output count with `.Select()` will return the length of your string.

**SOLUTION:**
*Calculates the number of lower 'a's only in the string as requested from Post Owner.*

```
public static int CountLowerAs(string input)
{
    return input.Count(x => x == 'a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Where` instead of `.Select`.  `.Where` finds items that match your criteria, whereas `.Select` tells it how to return said items if you need to transform them.